# Custom Exception Handling in Spring Boot with JSP

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsp, custom-error-pages

I am new to Spring Boot with JSP development and I am a bit lost when it comes to handling exceptions.

This is my scenario:

1. User clicks on a User from the JSP
2. Through a path variable I retrieve user id.
3. I then pass the user id to a service class.
4. The service class will query for the user by connecting with the `JPARepository`

The place where I am confused is this.

If the returned object is a null, should I return that `null` object or should I throw a custom exception like `ResourceNotFoundException` and then have catch statements in the controller methods?

Please. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Using ajax fire a call to retrieve user/id. If null then display “not found” on jsp for the end user. If found, set it to your desired service. The key is - always show some simple error message to end user(s) in case of null.

Comment: Bur doesn't spring allow throwing custom exceptions like UserNotFoundException and use ControllerAdvice?

Comment: And doesn't spring security also throw an exception when the user is not found while logging in?

Comment: Of course you can handle the exception gracefully. Give it a try.